# FieldError at /autocomplete/ItemsAutocomplete/

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I am using autocomplete_light in a django model form.

this is my model for the form

```
class Ca_dispensaries_item(TimeStampedModel):
  item = models.ForeignKey(Items)
  dispensary = models.ForeignKey(Ca_dispensaries)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True)
```

this is the form

```
class CamenuForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = Ca_dispensaries_item
     exclude = ('dispensary',)
     autocomplete_fields = ('item',)
```

registered as

```
autocomplete_light.register(Items, search_fields=('item_name'))
```

when i try to enter some values in the `item`, as per the autocomplete feature, it starts searching but gives `field error`
`Cannot resolve keyword u'i' into field. Choices are: arizona_dispensaries_item, ca_dispensaries_item, colorado_dispensaries_item, created, id`
i dont know from where this `i` is coming from. also, dispensaries_items are some of the models. while `created` and `id` are field names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgottent a comma! Change

`search_fields=('item_name')`

to

`search_fields=('item_name',)`

`search_fields` should be an iterable, so if it has the value `('item_name')` (which is a string) it will get 'i', 't', 'e', etc (that's why you get the message `Cannot resolve keyword u'i' into field`)

Also, there are some serious problems with the names your models: I see that you have a model named `Items` and a model named `Ca_dispensaries_item`. You should not name your models in plural, so `Items` should be `Item` and you need to use CamelCase with class names, so `Ca_dispensaries_item` should be CaDispensariesItem``.

Comment: No problem! Please consider also my naming suggestions !

Comment: Can you tell me how to add extra filter on the `item` depending on the value passed to the form as in "form = CamenuForm(request.POST or None, category=category)". I have tried using choices_for_request as well but i guess the method is not able to access the value passed

Comment: This is the link for problem:   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528414/how-to-create-a-dependant-drop-down-using-autocomplete-light)