# how to create a dependant drop down using autocomplete light

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I have created a form using `Django Model Form` and `autocomplete_light`. I want to filter the suggestions in the drop down list `item` according to the arguement passed when the class is called.

My form is

```
class CamenuForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = Ca_dispensaries_item
     exclude = ('dispensary',)
     autocomplete_fields = ('item',)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.category = kwargs.pop('category', None)
    super(CamenuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['item'].queryset=Items.objects.filter(product_type__name=self.category)
```

I have applied a filter in `__init__` according to the value of `category` passed but it doesnot seems to work.

The registry is

```
autocomplete_light.register(Items,search_fields=('item_name',))
```

And the form is called as

```
form = CamenuForm(request.POST or None, category=category)
```

Please suggest me a way so that I can refine the search based on the value passed while calling form.

I have tried to modify it by using

```
class AutoComplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
   search_fields=('item_name',)
   def choices_for_request(self):
        category = self.request.POST.get('category', 'none')
        print category
        choices = self.choices.all()
        if category:
            choices = choices.filter(product_type__name=category)
        return self.order_choices(choices)[0:self.limit_choices]
```

and registry as
    autocomplete_light.register(Items, AutoComplete )
Through this, I get to know that category gets the value `none` (because of the default value I chose) and this method also doesnt seems to work.

IS there a way that the value of `category` can be passed to `request_for_choices` so that the serach can be refined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `self.request.POST` (or `self.request.GET`) `QueryDict` of an Autocomplete class *will not* contain any more information than the search query because they are *not* passed when the view is created (so `self.request.POST.get('category', 'none')` will always return `'none'`).

So the difficult part is to somehow pass an argument (`category`) to a completely different view. This could be done, for instance by modifying the javascript that calls the autocomplete. Meaning, you'll need to change `getQuery` (http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/stable-2.x.x/script.html#override-autocomplete-js-methods) to append `category=foo` to the url that is called and then, at `choices_for_request` read the `self.request.GET` `QueryDict`to get that value.

Another way to do it is to put the category parameter to your session and then read the session in the `choices_for_request`. For example, on the `__init__` of your view you'll do something like `self.request.session['category'] = 'foo'` and on the `choices_for_request` you'll get that value.

Comment: what i find out is that `__init__` is not working with autocomplete. I have tried printing `something` in `__init__` which doesnot worked. When I have removed autocomplete model from the class, `something` gets prints and hence __init__ worked.

Comment: My fault. `init` was working. I printed the message in some other class. Well, I have used modified session variable in the place where form is called and then retrieved in choices. The prblem which now arises is explicit `choices_for_request` gives all the filtered suggestion not according to the text entered..:(